# how to get links using beautiful soup based on some condition

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract links based upon the guid values which are as follows:

```
[<guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32475840</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32461484</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32461442</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32355441</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32343707</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32317470</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32317460</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32317451</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32312587</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32298984</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32292851</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32280309</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32210693</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32117292</guid>,
 <guid ispermalink="false">pubmed:32116486</guid>]
```

or to extract the links based upon the values in the 'a' tag, for example I want to select only those links below with the following values

32475840, 32461484, 32461422 etc.

```
[<a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32475840/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32475840</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7265015/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC7265015</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.1136/bmjdrc-2020-001325">10.1136/bmjdrc-2020-001325</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32461484/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32461484</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_1401_19">10.4103/ijo.IJO_1401_19</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32461442/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32461442</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_1398_19">10.4103/ijo.IJO_1398_19</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32355441/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32355441</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7190579/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC7190579</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32343707/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32343707</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7188226/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC7188226</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0231901">10.1371/journal.pone.0231901</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317470/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32317470</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_1357_19">10.4103/ijo.IJO_1357_19</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317460/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32317460</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_1553_19">10.4103/ijo.IJO_1553_19</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317451/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32317451</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_244_19">10.4103/ijo.IJO_244_19</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32312587/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32312587</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaim.2020.02.002">10.1016/j.jaim.2020.02.002</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32298984/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32298984</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7146694/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC7146694</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dsx.2020.03.014">10.1016/j.dsx.2020.03.014</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32292851/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32292851</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7141917/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC7141917</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32280309/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32280309</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7137317/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC7137317</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.1186/s12962-020-00211-1">10.1186/s12962-020-00211-1</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32210693/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32210693</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC6997866/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC6997866</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.1016/j.sjbs.2019.12.007">10.1016/j.sjbs.2019.12.007</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32117292/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32117292</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7026189/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC7026189</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.3389/fimmu.2020.00154">10.3389/fimmu.2020.00154</a>,
 <a href="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32116486/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">32116486</a>,
 <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7020445/?utm_source=Feeder&amp;utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_campaign=pubmed-2&amp;utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&amp;fc=20200625034601&amp;ff=20200629043358&amp;v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4">PMC7020445</a>,
 <a href="https://doi.org/10.3389/fnins.2019.01445">10.3389/fnins.2019.01445</a>]
```

there are a total of 37 links on the rss feed:

```
['https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32475840/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7265015/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.1136/bmjdrc-2020-001325',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32461484/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_1401_19',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32461442/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_1398_19',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32355441/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7190579/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32343707/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7188226/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0231901',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317470/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_1357_19',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317460/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_1553_19',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317451/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_244_19',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32312587/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaim.2020.02.002',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32298984/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7146694/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dsx.2020.03.014',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32292851/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7141917/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32280309/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7137317/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.1186/s12962-020-00211-1',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32210693/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC6997866/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.1016/j.sjbs.2019.12.007',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32117292/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7026189/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.3389/fimmu.2020.00154',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32116486/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/PMC7020445/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://doi.org/10.3389/fnins.2019.01445']
```

I'm only looking for the 15 links whose ids are listed in the guid. How can I do this ? Also is there a way to change the isPermalink value to True, given that it is False in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it this way:

```
results = feed.find_all('a')
count = 0
list_of_sites = []
for i in results:
  count = count + 1
  if (feed.find_all('a')[count-1]).string.isdigit():
    list_of_sites.append((feed.find_all('a')[count-1]).get('href'))
```

the values in list_of_sites are:

```
['https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32475840/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32461484/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32461442/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32355441/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32343707/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317470/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317460/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32317451/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32312587/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32298984/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32292851/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32280309/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32210693/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32117292/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4',
 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32116486/?utm_source=Feeder&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pubmed-2&utm_content=1jq74NZspErHZpX3J2B97GZMF7znbt0391VdUGxV1hA6J5hMMP&fc=20200625034601&ff=20200629043358&v=2.9.2.post7+521c2b4']
```

exactly what I was looking for.